# Why does Silvermoon Guardian say "Remember Quel'Thalas"?

Tags: warcraft

In Hearthstone: Heroes of Warcraft, the "Silvermoon Guardian", when entering play, says "Remember Quel'Thalas!"

I wonder what does it mean. As I gather, Quel'Thalas is an ancient elven realm with the capital city named Silvermoon. So does it simply mean "Remember you fight for your country" or does it have a deeper meaning, perhaps Quel'Thalas was a site of an important battle where they made some mistake?

Comment: Silvermoon is (was) the capital of the Kingdom of Quel'Thalas, not the other way round.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández Thank you. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> or does it have a deeper meaning, perhaps Quel'Thalas was a site of an important battle where they made some mistake?

Yes.  During the Third War, Arthas, with the assistance of Dar'Khan Drathir, basically marched his Scourge from the Eastern Plaguelands, through the Ghostlands, though Quel'Thalas, destroyed Silvermoon ([Half the city is still ruins](http://wowpedia.org/Ruins_of_Silvermoon)), killed the majority of the High Elves, killed King Anasterian, killed Sylvanas Windrunner (turning her into the first banshee), and used the Sunwell to resurrect Kel'Thuzad, corrupting the Sunwell (and depriving the High Elves of the source of their power) in the process

The path he took is still corrupted and is called the Dead Scar.

[image]

Comment: Also, in World of Warcraft, when you talk to some Blood Elves NPCs, they sometimes say "Remember the Sunwell". I guess it's for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is this: Silvermoon guards  will say "Remember Quel'thalas", because their homes were destroyed. They says those words for their enemy as words of revenge: "This is for Quel'thalas!" And they will never forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

Both, sort of.  For all intents and purposes the nation of Quel'Thalas was destroyed in the Third War, as 90% of the High Elves were butchered in the genocidal rampage by the traitor-prince, Arthas, and the undead swarms composed of the fallen population of Lordaeron.  It would be like if the USA was destroyed and all that survived was Chicago...sure technically Americans still live, but basically everything we were was wiped out.

Quel'Thalas' primary defense was the great barrier shield known as the Ban'dinoriel, powered by the Sunwell, that protected the country of the High Elves for 7000 years.  Only by the help of a traitor was the shield deactivated and kept from being re-formed, allowing the undead to breach the conventional defenses.